# Force sqlite select query to return nothing instead of null

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query similar to this:

```
select distinct 'density' as feature, density as value, 
       count(density) as frequency 
from cases
where density in not null;
```

Let's call it query A, and the next query is query B.

In the case when the query B:

```
select distinct density as value, count(density) as frequency 
from cases
where density in not null;
```

returns nothing, query A returns a line contains:

```
('density', null, null)
```

but I want from query A to return nothing. The question is, how to refactor the query A to force it to return nothing in the explained case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
select 'density' as feature, density as value, 
       count(density) as frequency 
from cases
where density is not null
group by density;
```

If all the rows are filtered out by the `where`, then the `group by` will return no rows at all.